# java creating an ArrayList of objects that inherit from different classes

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist

I am confused.
I have created an abstract class 'Person'  then I extend class 'Part-Time Employee' from Person. 
Then I extend an abstract class from Person called 'Full-Time Employee'.
Then I create two new classes called 'New Full-Time Employee' and 'Tenured Full-Time Employee' that both extend from Full-Time Employee.

I want to keep track of all of the employees in an ArrayList... and this is where I am conceptually stuck.  I create a class called Database that extends from ArrayList.

How can I make sure that the array can hold all 3 classes that I need?  Do I make the array of the Abstract class type?  That makes me think that I wouldn't have access to the methods that I defined in the inherited classes... I have also read that it is not good practice to extends from the ArrayList...so would it make sense to create a database class with an ArrayList ? Would that still allow me access to everything I have defined down the line?

Like if I am wanting to display the whole list, how will it know which display function to use?  Either the tenuredFullTimeEmployee's or the NewFullTimeEmployee's?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You do have some options. If the classes only differ in behavior, then you can use the strategy pattern. If you really need to keep objects of different types in a List object and then do different things based on that type, you can use the visitor pattern. My guess is that you should ditch some of that inheritance and go for something like strategy that abstracts the behavior that differs out of the classes.

http://www.oodesign.com/strategy-pattern.html

http://www.oodesign.com/visitor-pattern.html

To answer your second question, you are right... rather than extend ArrayList, you should have something like

```
List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

Then using one of the two suggested patterns above, you can handle the differing behaviors.